# ExtJS 4. How to set striperows in form panel?

Tags: css, extjs4

I have a very huge `form panel` with multiple fields. The only thing that makes it inconvenient is single background color. I want to use `stripeRows` functionality like in the grid component, so that even and odd fields will have slightly different background colors. I tried to use css long ago, but the effect was not good, because there were large paddings between field. So, what is the best way to restyle the form?

Comment: You can have a background that looks like strip rows and align you components accordingly to background. Or for each row in the panel you assign the style( may be grouping all the row contents in one container)

Comment: I think a backround with strip rows is not a good solution, because blocks of fields may not coincide with predifined strips on the background. As for assigning a style, I need some advice here. I tried to do this, but got large uncolored margins between rows

Comment: "uncolored margins between rows", do you have offset set ?

Comment: @objectone Thank you for advising. Actually, I got a solution at Sencha forum. The solution is to suspend layouts, then to parse all fields of the form like this - this.getForm().getFields() and finally to add a custom class to all fields. In any case the solution can be found at Sencha forum (though, in a private section). If you are interested in the complete solution, I can post it here, but a little bit later

Answer (score 0):

I found this article that explains how to easily do this:

http://skirtlesden.com/articles/styling-extjs-grid-cells

Comment: Thanks! But I see, this article is about grid, however I want to make a style for a form panel.